# Setting up Ansible community.libvirt.virt

Tags: python, ubuntu, ansible, system-administration

Has anyone successfully made community.libvirt.virt module work with Ansible? I cannot find a complete guide with all the necessary steps. I am running Ubuntu 18 on an AWS EC2.

I have been trying to get this working all day and am not having success. I've tried using both python2 and python3. I've tried installing via pip and via apt. I've tried installing various packages based on google searches (such as build-essential, libvirt-dev, libvirt-python, etc.).

This is my current error:

`` {"changed": false, "msg": "The `libvirt` module is not importable. Check the requirements."} ``

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Vanished when I switched to python3. There was a long forgotten line:

```
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python2
```

in my inventory.yml